# Magento 2 compile css error during upgrade

Tags: magento2, css, compilation, less-compilation

I have made some changes in CSS and upgrade as usually, it gives that error but suddenly hide from and no prob will come on CSS deploying but now it struck and I have no idea why.
I tried to recompile and then upgrade but this error is not going and CSS is not coming on front-end.

Another error comes after a long wait which is mmap() function that I also don't know of.
[image: logs]

Comment: Please check if the style sheet exists. If exists then PLEASE check if it is not empty. if empty then just remove it or delete it

Answer (score 0):

Stylesm.less should be Styles-m.less. So you may search for a reason why this string stylesm comes up.

Search for this string is the first step, let us know once you have found it.